# How to I set a http header for a soap call in soap4r?

Tags: ruby, web-services, soap, soap4r

How to I set a http header for a soap call in soap4r ?

```
@drv = SOAP::RPC::Driver.new('x', 'y')
```

How do I set a http header "vmware_soap_session" to call the calls that are going out of @drv ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a `header` hash parameter available with the `SOAP::NetHttpClient.get_content` and `SOAP::NetHttpClient.post` methods:

Here's the source for the first that helps 'splain it:

```
# File 'lib/soap/netHttpClient.rb', line 95

def get_content(url, header = {})
  if str = @test_loopback_response.shift
    return str
  end
  unless url.is_a?(URI)
    url = URI.parse(url)
  end
  extra = header.dup
  extra['User-Agent'] = @agent if @agent
  res = start(url) { |http|
    http.get(url.request_uri, extra)
  }
  res.body
end
```

Try setting the `header` hash to `{"vmware_soap_session" => true}` or whatever you're supposed to use as the value.